# Speeding up / Cancelling Transactions Stuck in Mempool

Tags: transactions, operation

If I have a transaction stuck in mempool, how can I cancel the transaction or pay more to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in Tezos there is no way to replace or cancel a transaction. So we would have to wait for it to be dropped (64 blocks ~64 minutes) from the mempool if transactions get stuck.

source: https://twitter.com/dsintermediatd/status/1286341689368551428

Comment: This was incorrect at the time of writing: it was 60 blocks (~60 minutes) for protocols until Florence, and 120 blocks and the same time, since Granada.