# Stuck transaction for more than 12 hours

Tags: node, transactions, error, mempool, trezor

i tried sending my funds from trezor Simple Staking wallet to the exchange, and it seems that the transaction is stuck.

[image]

i tried many recommendations online such as increasing the transaction fee but it keeps on showing the same error (see picture below)

[image]

This is my operation hash id: https://tzkt.io/op2MaaN9xxbJ59j1WC6YndRb7iMKJMZb3dSuPK4a465jE2PCJfR

from this link ([Speeding up / Cancelling Transactions Stuck in Mempool](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/speeding-up-cancelling-transactions-stuck-in-mempool)) it says it only takes 64 minutes to cancel a transaction but its been more than 12 hours in my situation.

When i check the balance the fund has not been moved.

Answer (score 1):

Both transactions sent from [your address](https://tzkt.io/tz1UF79FdS5Jvp9JEtLujrhBMZaBWKrtNbNy/operations/) have the same fee `0.01 tez` that is not enough, taking into account the gas limit `50000`. Try to set the fee `0.015 tez`. If this doesn't help, it also can be a problem with the node you use, so try to use another one, like [Tezos Giga Node](http://tezos.giganode.io/).

And yes, operations stay in the mempool for only an hour, however [TzKT explorer](https://tzkt.io/) stores them for several days in order to give you sufficient time to see/catch them and to investigate why a particular operation was rejected. Just like in your case =)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to send the transaction again with 1 xtz in transaction fee but still says the same mempool error...